# Multitask/multioutput GPy Coregionalized Regression with non-Gaussian Likelihood and Laplace inference function

Tags: python, data-science, gaussian-process, gpyopt, gpy

I want to perform coregionalized regression in GPy, however I am using a Bernoulli likelihood and then to estimate that as a Gaussian, I use Laplace inference. The code below shows how I would usually run a single-output GP with this set up (with my custom `PjkRbf` kernel):

```py
likelihood  = GPy.likelihoods.Bernoulli()
laplace_inf = GPy.inference.latent_function_inference.Laplace()
kernel      = GPy.kern.PjkRbf(X.shape[1])
m = GPy.core.GP(X, Y, kernel=kernel, likelihood=likelihood, inference_method=laplace_inf)
```

Now I am trying to run the same set up but as multi-output. This is something I have not been able to do.

I have tried using the `GPCoregionalizedRegression` class with an ICM kernel, as shown in the code below:

```py
likelihood1  = GPy.likelihoods.Bernoulli()
likelihood2 = GPy.likelihoods.Bernoulli()
laplace_inf = GPy.inference.latent_function_inference.Laplace()
K = GPy.kern.PjkRbf(X.shape[1])
icm = GPy.util.multioutput.ICM(input_dim=2,num_outputs=2,kernel=K)
m = GPy.models.GPCoregionalizedRegression([X,X],[Y1,Y2],
                                          kernel=icm, 
                                          likelihoods_list=[likelihood1, likelihood2])
```

Running this code throws an AssertionError, with a long stack-trace, but the last section shows the following. The likelihood cannot be asserted as a Gaussian.

```py
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\GPy\likelihoods\mixed_noise.py in gaussian_variance(self, Y_metadata)
     22 
     23     def gaussian_variance(self, Y_metadata):
---> 24         assert all([isinstance(l, Gaussian) for l in self.likelihoods_list])
     25         ind = Y_metadata['output_index'].flatten()
     26         variance = np.zeros(ind.size)

AssertionError:
```

This is because I am **not able to pass the Laplace inference** to the `GPCoregionalizedRegression` model.

Can anyone offer advice on how I can resolve this, or if there is a different model I can use to perform multioutput regression with a Bernoulli likelihood and Laplace inference method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you must not pass Laplace inference to `GPCoregionalizedRegression`, but that your list of `GPy.likelihoods.Bernoulli` likelihoods isn't supported.

In the [documentation](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/GPy.likelihoods.html#introduction) it reads

> Most likelihood classes inherit directly from GPy.likelihoods.likelihood, although an intermediary class GPy.likelihoods.mixed_noise.MixedNoise is used by GPy.likelihoods.multioutput_likelihood.

Since you set up a multi-output problem, the underlying likelihood is a `GPy.likelihoods.mixed_noise.MixedNoise` object, which does in GPy only support lists of `GPy.likelihoods.Gaussian` objects.

Compare [here](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/blob/3e19a85575687e37fd6f61174115d7c94d2c96e6/GPy/likelihoods/mixed_noise.py#L14) in the source code

```
class MixedNoise(Likelihood):
def __init__(self, likelihoods_list, name='mixed_noise'):
    #NOTE at the moment this likelihood only works for using a list of gaussians
    super(Likelihood, self).__init__(name=name)
```

Therefor the `assert` statement in `\GPy\likelihoods\mixed_noise.py`, which checks the `likelihood_list` items to be `Gaussian` fails as indicated by the stacktrace you posted.

As of now, this is still not implemented. I believe the development on `GPy` is considered of lower priority with respect to its successor `GPflow`. There  (according to the code used in [this](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.html#Constructing-the-model) example), it seems to me there are no restrictions on the type of likelihoods in the corresponding functions (even if the example again uses only Gaussian likelihoods)